# list membership requests WITH answers to questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook API endpoint `/v2.11/{GROUP_ID}/member_requests/` allows me to list membership requests to group I have permission.

I'm looking method/idea/etc to list membership requests WITH answers to questions (my group requires answering questions when user wants to join).

Do you have any ideas how can I achieve this?

Best regards,
Milosz

Comment: what does the api reference say?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same.
I currently found https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/reference/member to list members, but still can't get members' answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this via the API. However, there are some Chrome Extensions that allow you to save the answers to those questions!

Check out [GroupTrack CRM](https://www.grouptrackcrm.com)...it's a CRM that is integrated into Facebook via a Chrome Extension. It does what you're looking for (one click to approve individual or all pending members while also saving their answers to your questions and adding them to the CRM), along with a ton of other awesome stuff.

Keep notes and tags, track sales funnel stages, bookmark posts and comments, set follow up tasks with reminders, and more across unlimited Groups. Everything is synced in real time with a web app as well, so you can access your contact information from anywhere, plus it can be set up to integrate with external systems (Google Sheets, Streak, and Kartra at the moment, but many more to come).

Lastly, GroupTrack supports teams, so if you run a Group with other admins, you can share access to the CRM and have everything kept in sync. It's awesome!